# ASP.NET core 1.1 - getting 404 on js files placed under views folders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I really like the folder structure "Features folder" for ASP.NET Core 1.1 (se here https://scottsauber.com/2016/04/25/feature-folder-structure-in-asp-net-core/).

So here's my structure...

```
- Features
  - Home
    - index.cshtml
    - index.js
    - homeController.cs
```

In my index.cshtml, I have this js link:

```
<script src="/home/index.js"></script>
```

But when I run the app, I can see the index.cshtml fine, but I get an 404 error on the index.js file.

I've tried changing the `"Build action" to "Content"` ... that didn't help.

In startup, I have this ... `app.UseStaticFiles();`

Any idea how to make ASP.Net core 1.1 accept files placed in view folders?

Comment: I think you are missing `RAMMFAR` entry in `web.config`. add `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> </system.webServer>`

Comment: Also, I had similar problem due to `case sensitivity`.  make sure the path is `case sensitive`.  `home` to `Home`.

Comment: Web.config is not created by default in core 1.1 (VS RC2017RC), so I created it and added your code, but it didn't work. All my controllers, views, js files etc is in lowecases - so that is not the problem either. Hmmmmm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static contents are served in wwwroot folder, either move your index.js in wwwroot/home/index.js (recommanded solution) or change your wwwroot config to point on your Features folder (not recommanded)